# How to edit custom css and java script In Magento 2

Tags: layout, javascript, magento-2.0, less-css

How to change the less, css and java script In Magento 2?
in check the style located in pub folder?. 
where i edit the styles?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create custom theme first read this [How to create a storefront theme?](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

**Apply new created theme from backend** given path below

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
```

Then you have to configure compilation of style in admin path given below

```
Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Front-end development workflow
```

change to

```
Client side less compilation
```

Then edit your theme styles `module wise` and other `web/css/source` (common style and js as well)

```
app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name
```

run below command to set developer mode

```
- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

and clear cache and deploy static-content

```
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: every change the css code we deploy the static-content?..

Comment: No just first time, Once you `configure compilation` then you changes will display.